# Blender 2.90.1|Where's the UV Layout Export function?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm using Blender 2.90.1 and I can't see the UV Layout Export

In older versions, it has located on UV Editor > UV > Export UV Layout

It's gone?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure "Import-Export: UV Layout" is enabled in the addons section of user preferences:

[image: UVLayout]